# Transparency font rendering issues in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flex4, transparency, alpha

EDIT/Solved: This seems to have mysteriously solved itself. I am still running the same Chrome build, same machine, and I have not rebuilt the SWF. The only difference I can thing of has been closing the browser and hibernating over night ...

I am having problems in Chrome with the rendering of a Label in ButtonBarButton, and I am trying to find a way to work around it (unsuccessfully). As you can see, transparency is generally working - the background of the unselected tab has alpha=0, so it is just the area around the font causing problems.

Does anyone know of a workaround? Verified as problem in Chrome on both Windows and OS X. All other browsers displays the tab fine, which is not surprising given that Chrome ships with its own Flash plugin ...

**A correct rendering of the transparent tab in Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

**Chrome's rendering of the same thing**

[image: Chrome]

Using OS X 10.6.8, Flex SDK 4.6, FlashBuilder 4.7, Firefox 18.02, Chrome 24.0.1312.57.
All as updated as can be as of February 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This might be another problem with Chrome's buggy Pepper Flash player. It has many issues.  You can confirm if Pepper Flash is the problem by disabling it. When you do that, Chrome will use the more standard Flash plugin, which should also be installed.

To disable it go to: chrome://plugins

Click the plus icon (details icon) and find the Flash plugins. Disable the one that has "PepperFlash" in the path.

Pepper Flash is a great idea, but its not quite as stable as the regular flash plugin.

Comment: sorry, but it seems to have solved itself. a good nights sleep and a browser close seems to have fixed it, but I _did_ verify the problem on another Windows install of Chrome, so it was not just me.